# MySQL secondary tables by table type reference

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of 'posts' that contains post_type and primary key of a corresponding table, whereby for each post_type there is a corresponding table.

I would like to retrieve the data from the corresponding tables as if to populate the entries in a social feed style wall. e.g. The final data aught to be able to be packaged up as JSON entities.

Here are some screenshots to illustrate my database tables:

`

### Posts

[image: Posts]

`

### Games

[image: Games]

`

### Achievements

[image: Achievements]

`

### Videos

[image: Videos]

I'm new to MySQL queries and so I have a couple of considerations, I am wondering if this is possible using the CASE statement of MySQL. I have added a snippet of **PSEUDO CODE** that hopefully illustrates a little what I have in mind.

```
SELECT * FROM posts
            CASE 
                WHEN posts.post_type = 'game' THEN 
                    INNER JOIN games ON (games.game_id = posts.origin_id)
                WHEN posts.post_type = 'achievement' THEN
                    INNER JOIN achievements ON (achievements.achievement_id = posts.origin_id)
                WHEN posts.post_type = 'event' THEN
                    INNER JOIN events ON (event.event_id = posts.origin_id)
            END;
```

Alternatively if this is **NOT** possible, efficient or practical, then I would really appreciate an more efficient alternative approach. I created an SQLFiddle with some sample database tables etc (NOT 100% accurate, just for testing).

An option I have been told about is using LEFT JOINS and I am experimenting with them here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7fdde/2

However I have not been able to effectively get the entity data using PHP without data loss / corruption. It's clear that there is missing entity data or even additional data such as missing created_at and updated_at entries and addition 1000 likes entry in the 2nd entity.

https://gist.github.com/PluginIO/ec9c411f75859570a087c53ca4671f3e

I tried to remove the NULL values from the LEFT JOINS with the following PHP routines:

https://gist.github.com/PluginIO/2444d2fb1098ebb3248f4fb84751d831

Last but not least, a commenter below offered an alternative approach that uses INNER JOINS and UNIONS however I have been unable to get that working:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7fdde/12

Hopefully it is quite clear that the result that I am hoping for is a sequential set of post entities with its own relevant table data in a JSON formatted list.

Regards

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: using `subquery` will lower your performance you can just simply achieve your result with `joins` check my answer

Comment: try my updated answer if possible move the discussion to chatroom so we can fix it as you like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sub query` instead of the `join`. Don't use `subquery` if `subquery` table `return more than one row` for specific `id`.

Check this SQL Fiddle: [Click Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6e413/27/0)

```
  SELECT * ,CASE 
                    WHEN posts.post_type = 'game' THEN 
                        ( SELECT games.name from games where games.game_id = posts.origin_id)
                    WHEN posts.post_type = 'achievement' THEN
                        ( SELECT achievements.name FROM achievements WHERE  achievements.achievement_id = posts.origin_id)
                       END as value_name FROM posts;
```

Hope this query helpful to you.

Comment: That does seem close however when I try it, I get a syntax error. I edited my post above to contain your example and a simple SQLFiddle. I'm not quite sure of your intension where that syntax error occurs. Would you be so kind as to clarify? :)

Comment: @GaryPaluk, i just edit  my answer and it is also working in sqlfiddle, this is the output which you expact?

Comment: While it may function, the performance will not be good and it will not scale.

Comment: The results are exactly what I hoped for, but given the notion that this won't scale, I'm totally open to solutions that scale. I'm new to MySQL querying and so any better examples would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this updated your fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6e413/34

```
SELECT p.*,g.*,a.* from posts p 
          LEFT JOIN games g
              ON 
                 p.post_type = 'game' AND 
                 g.game_id = p.origin_id
          LEFT JOIN achievements a
              ON 
                 p.post_type='achievement' AND
                 a.achievement_id = p.origin_id
```

**EDIT**

Read data from mysql php :

```
  $post = array();
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {    
        /* fetch object array */
        while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {
            array_push($post,$obj);
        }
     }

vardump($post);
```

There will be few elements which returns `null` in every line

To remove `NULL` or `empty` field from array :

php :

```
foreach($array as &$value) {
    $value = array_filter($value, function($v) {    return ! empty( $value ); });
}

 // $array = array_map('array_filter', $array);
```

refer : http://codepad.org/FdfY5aqj

Comment: This has worked perfectly, and I appreciate your comment. I have left the other comment as the correct answer as it does answer my original question but thanks so much! Is it normal to remove those NULL values using an object iteration and unset in PHP? I produce the following JSON using your LEFT JOIN - http://imgur.com/a/Xc2d4

while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
 foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
  if(!isset($value)) {
   unset($row->$key);
  }
 }
 array_push($posts, $row);
}

I used this, but it seems that it causes missing entries where there are NULL duplicates. Thanks

Comment: please refer my answer i have updated to remove `null` values

Comment: Seems to be working fine in your example but something wrong when I add it in my own code: https://gist.github.com/PluginIO/1f077318abfc8554b384b58a7c833b64

I just get {"posts":[null,null]} out from the JSON encoder :(

Comment: Please check `$row` returning any values first else try my updated answer

Comment: I changed it to fetch_assoc() to return an array and I get data agian but I have the same problem. For example, where there are two columns with the same name, but one is NULL, it removes the entries completely for all types. So if we use your example at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38f96/3 - It will remove game_id and name on all entites.

Comment: can you please share your json array ?

Comment: posts: http://imgur.com/eXlhX86 - games: http://imgur.com/62h7MVn - games_achievements: http://imgur.com/0UK2q1k - videos: http://imgur.com/Nj7hS22 - query: https://gist.github.com/PluginIO/2444d2fb1098ebb3248f4fb84751d831 - JSON: https://gist.github.com/PluginIO/ec9c411f75859570a087c53ca4671f3e - As you see, there are missing fields, game_id, created_at, updated_at etc... :) - I tried your updated code whilst compiling this message but it resulted in NULL data again. Please feel free to move this to a discussion chat. Thank you :D

Comment: did you get the fields you are expecting in the `$row` variable ?

Comment: No, those variables do not seem to be in the $row variable (They appear NULL when they are not NULL in the database). I tested using print_r. https://gist.github.com/PluginIO/5b83445402e670383dc67ead0c727618

Comment: yea because `created_date` is common for both table you should `select `them individually instead of using `*` eg : `select g.created_date ,a.created_date`

Comment: Is that also true when you select as; p.*, g.*, a.*, v.*, etc? Such as in my query example: https://gist.github.com/PluginIO/2444d2fb1098ebb3248f4fb84751d831 - I would like to retain fields such as created_at and updated_at for all returned entities.

Comment: Change your query like this : 
`SELECT p.created_date as post_created_date,g.created_date as games_created_date,,a.created_date  as achievement_created_date,v.created_date as video_created_date from posts p
 `

Comment: Really? For every property? This is horrible, verbose and seems like it cannot be maintainable solution?! It would also require remapping back to the original names anyway!

Comment: you got no choice even when using `subquery` you might get the same result

Answer (score 1):

That you think you can retrieve the data with a SELECT statement implies that the tables games, achievements and events contain a common (sub)set of attributes (although the tables have different prefixes on the '_id' field, the data domain is the same in each case). In the absence of any further information, these should not have been designed as separate tables but rather should have used a single table with an attribute for 'type' and seperate tables detailling any non-common attributes. Indeed, if all that is contained in the 'posts' table is an id and an identifier for the table containing the data, it becomes redundant at this point - you should have 1 table, not 4.

Amongst other issues, you would not have the problem you describe above.

If you have already gone well down the road of implementing a system around this design and fixing the problem is too expensive, then you can apply a workaround by:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT a.achievent_id AS common_id, .....
   FROM achievements a
   UNION
   SELECT g.game_id, .....
   FROM games g
   UNION
   SELECT e.event_id, ....
   FROM events e
 ) AS ilv
   ON p.id=ilv.id
```

Where ... represents the common attributes.

But in addition to not supplying the details of the table structures, nor did you tell us how the query will be filtered - I doubt you want to retrieve the entire data set each and every time you run the query. How you implement the filtering will have a big impact on the performance.

If the number of rows is most reduced by the filtering on the posts table (i.e. using some attribute you've not told us about) then selecting the union of the join (rather than joining to the union) would be more efficient:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN
achievements a
ON p.id=a.achievement_id
WHERE p.user=?
UNION
SELECT *
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN
events e
ON p.id=e.evet_id
WHERE p.user=?
UNION
SELECT *
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN
games g
ON p.id=g.game_id
WHERE p.user=?
```

Comment: Actually, in reality, there are only a few common elements across those tables and most of the table content is different. I have been able to achieve the desired result using LEFT JOINs but thank you very much for your comment. It's all valuable information to me. :)

Comment: I think I'm hitting some of the issues that you foresaw. I tried to provide further information. You were also correct that I would filter the results. I have a user table with user_id field and also have OFFSET and LIMIT values. - posts: http://imgur.com/eXlhX86 - games: http://imgur.com/62h7MVn - games_achievements: http://imgur.com/0UK2q1k - videos: http://imgur.com/Nj7hS22 - query: http://gist.github.com/PluginIO/2444d2fb1098ebb3248f4fb84751d831 - JSON: http://gist.github.com/PluginIO/ec9c411f75859570a087c53ca4671f3e ... I guess this SQLFiddle is closer. - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7fdde/2

Comment: After multiple attempts, I could not get your example working due to errors with 'different number of columns': http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7fdde/12 :(

Comment: You didn't tell us what the table structures were. There are several solutions - padding with dummy columns to create a virtual, common representation in the SELECT, serializing the differing columns to a (deserializable) string being obvious ones.

Comment: Yes, I attempted to change your query to reflect the requirements of the table structures. I did amend the original post as I realised that the information that I provided might not cover the alternative recommendations that people brought to the conversation. Perhaps you would be kind enough to update the SQLFiddle to represent your recommendation based on the updated info? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7fdde/12

Comment: Sorry - access to sqlfiddle.com is blocked from here.